# Numpy Library not loading(In face none of the library)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have installed Python 3.7, and I have been working in Python for a while. It was working all fine and suddenly from this afternoon, I am unable to load any Python libraries. I have tried to uninstall and install entire libraries and Python itself. It has not fixed the issue yet. Could someone help on what else to be looked at. I have been using pip3 to install packages. I am not using Anaconda. I was able to install the package successfully but unable to load for some reason. When I try to load numpy, I am getting below mentioned error

```
import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The network path was not found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\chango3\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

Original error was: `DLL load failed: The network path was not found.`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? May try upgrading as an administrator: `pip uninstall numpy` and then `pip install numpy --upgrade`

Comment: Error message says to start from scratch. What happens when you try that?

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to fix it. It is because of the Firewall I was not able to connect. When I am in the network, I was able to access, but when I am not in the network, I was unable to access. That was the difference.